# My Android app crashes even though I am catching the exception it says is causing the crash

Tags: java, android, exception

Here is my code:

```
private ArrayList<PInfo> getSelectedPackages() {
    ArrayList<PInfo> apps = new ArrayList<PInfo>();
    for (String aname : Lock.getAllowedApps()) {
        try {
            PackageInfo pi = getPackageManager().getPackageInfo(aname, 0);
            PInfo newInfo = new PInfo(pi.applicationInfo, getPackageManager());
            apps.add(newInfo);
        } catch (NameNotFoundException e) {
            ErrorReporter.getInstance().handleSilentException(e);
        }
    }
    return apps;
}
```

The line that crashes is:

```
PackageInfo pi = getPackageManager().getPackageInfo(aname, 0);
```

Which doesn't make any sense as I'm catching the error. Hope someone can tell me what I'm doing wrong or that is's some sort of bug with Android. This is what the log shows:

```
android.content.pm.PackageManager$NameNotFoundException: com.teachersparadise.dinosaurscoloringbook at android.app.ContextImpl$ApplicationPackageManager.getPackageInfo(ContextImpl.java:1725) at com.nyanapps.lockfortots.free.Home.getSelectedPackages(Home.java:179)
```

Answer (score 1):

You may want to make certain your package name string is formatted correctly, and you may not be catching the correct exception.

Notice that the exception is PackageManager.NameNotFoundException

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/pm/PackageManager.NameNotFoundException.html

Comment: The package name is given to me by the package manager(PM). I request a list of all installed apps from the PM and display show the user, they pick from the list, and I save their selection. Then, in a diff activity I read the saved info and generate icons and labels which I request from the PM. I'd imagine if I had the package name wrong the error would be thrown at the time of creating the icons and labels . That's why I'm confused because if it were wrong how does the PM give me the icon and label from the same wrong info.

Comment: Thanks for the link by the way. I will read it to see if I learn anything new.

Answer (score 0):

You are probably catching [`javax.naming.NameNotFoundException`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/naming/NameNotFoundException.html) while the exception thrown is [`android.content.pm.PackageManager$NameNotFoundException`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/pm/PackageManager.NameNotFoundException.html)

Try to `catch (Exception e)` and check if it is indeed your issue.

Comment: Well I checked my imports, and the only NameNotFoundException class I am importing is android.content.pm.PackageManager.NameNotFoundException. I was really hoping I had it wrong when I checked because that would have been an easy fix. Really appreciate the suggestion. I hadn't even thought of checking that but now it will be the first thing I check if ever I have a similar situation arise. Also FYI I have not been able to recreate the issue on my own phone. I use google ACRA to report errors and only users of my app have had the problem. I've even tried un-installing an app after selecting it

Comment: so that my app would attempt to request the info and have it not be found, but using the same try... catch clause it doesn't occur. That's one reason I'd assumed I had the code write.